# maya python, polyvertexpernormal

Tags: python, foreach, maya

So in a nutshell I am needing to export the vertex normals from a character into a text file, or whatever, and then reimport them onto the same character in a different scene.

I have the import export part working in a method that I think is ok, but actually going through the loop and setting the normal on each vertex is taking over twenty minutes and usually overloads the ram on my machine and crashes maya.

I guess I am looking for a way to make my code more efficient or just run faster, any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
def ImoNorms(self):
    ll = mc.ls ('head.vtxFace[*][*]')
    input = open('My desktop.txt', 'r')
    spltOne = ll[:len(ll)/2]
    spltTwo = ll[len(ll)/2:]


    i = 0
    for each in spltOne:
        CurrentLine = input.readline() 


        kk = re.split(r'\[|\]|\,|\/n|\ ',CurrentLine)
        aa = float(kk[1])
        aa = round(aa, 3)

        bb = float(kk[3])
        bb = round(bb,3)

        cc = float(kk[5])
        cc = round(cc,3)


        mc.select(each)
        mc.polyNormalPerVertex(xyz =(aa, bb, cc))
        i = i + 1
        if i%1000 == 0:
            print i    

init()
```

Sorry for the formatting issues, still new to this site.

Comment: you can click on the little `?` button to get help for formatting, if you then click on the `Code` button it explains how to use the `{}` code formatting button.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that for the future.

Comment: Can you post the contents of one of the files you're reading?

To speed it up I wouldn't use pymel as it's quite slow (switch to cmds or OpenMaya with `MFnMesh`).

You can also speed it up by avoiding regular expressions (`re` module).

Avoid using `select`, and instead just pass the vertex directly to `polyNormalPerVertex`

Comment: Here is a basic example of a few lines. There are about 32000 per file. 

head1.vtxFace[2463][0]$[0.6252811551094055, -0.7362512946128845, 0.2587616443634033]

head1.vtxFace[230][0]$[0.6828765869140625, -0.6926679611206055, 0.23214386403560638]

head1.vtxFace[2464][0]$[0.6639131903648376, -0.6957235932350159, 0.27420440316200256]

head1.vtxFace[6339][0]$[0.6271862387657166, -0.7240926623344421, 0.2869270145893097]

head1.vtxFace[2464][1]$[0.6639131903648376, -0.6957235932350159, 0.27420440316200256]

Answer (score 0):

What you have will be very slow because you are creating a lot of history on your mesh: if you exit out of the loop after a couple of iterations you'll see that your mesh is accumulating a `polyNormalPerVertex` node for every iteration.

Unfortunately there's no way to turn of construction history for this command (which seems like an oversight: most commands have a `ch` flag for exactly this purpose).  So the first thing to try is to add an `mc.delete(ch=True)` after every `polyNormalPerVertex` call. That will be much faster and it might be enough for what you're doing.

Otherwise you'll need to use the OpenMaya api, which is a bit harder than `cmds` but will let you do bulk normal operations faster.  I would get the `cmds` version working first and see if it's good enough, it should be much more performant without the history overhead.

**UPDATE**

Unless you want to learn the API to do this, the right thing is probably:

1. Save out the mesh with the right normals as an MB or MA file
2. in the other file, load that mesh and use [Transfer Attributes](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-76D5F064-C5A1-4310-B72A-788AB5C9A25B-htm.html) to copy the normals across.
3. Delete history and remove the mesh you loaded in (2)

That gets you off the hook for both making your own file format and for perf issues, plus it gives you pre-made options for cases where the topology does not line up for some reason

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out now.

Comment: It didn't seem to affect the speed at all.

Comment: Are you still generating the history nodes? They'll show up in the channelbox.  You may need to save the name of the mesh itself and call that explicitly, especially if you followed the advice in the other answer and didn't use `cmds.select()` (which is good advice, btw)

Comment: Actually I tried it with dummy data and it is still unconscionably slow - seems to run about almost 7-8 seconds per thousand vertices.  The lack of history should prevent the memory overflow at least but wont' make it snappy -- you'll probably need to use the API

Answer (score 0):

+1 to using `OpenMaya` if you want better performance.

Check out `MFnMesh.getNormals` and `MFnMesh.setNormals`. I admit I haven't used these methods myself, but if it's anything like `MFnMesh.setPoints` it should be a significant boost in speed as it's setting the normals all at once. Seems like you don't have to deal with its history either.

Here's an example on its usage that will re-direct all of a sphere's vert normals to point down. (Go to Display->Polygons->Vertex Normals to visualize the normals)

```
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


# Create a sphere to change vert normals with
mesh_obj, _ = cmds.polySphere()

# Wrap sphere as MDagPath object
sel = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
sel.add(mesh_obj)
dag_path = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
sel.getDagPath(0, dag_path)

# Pass sphere to mesh function set
mesh_fn = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(dag_path)

# Create empty vector array
vec_array = OpenMaya.MFloatVectorArray()

# Get sphere normals and stuff data in our vector array
mesh_fn.getNormals(vec_array, OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject)
for i in range( vec_array.length() ):
    # Point all normals downwards
    vec_array[i].assign( OpenMaya.MFloatVector(0, -1, 0) )

# Apply normals back to sphere 
mesh_fn.setNormals(vec_array, OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject)
```

You may also want to consider a different way on how you read your file instead of reading each line one by one. Maybe using `json.dumps` to store the data to a file and `json.loads` to retrieve the data. This could potentially speed things up.